# Javascript image slider not working properly

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create an image slider with controls "Next" and "Previous". Next should slide the image left using a negative margin-left property so as to reveal the second image. All the list elements holding individual images are set to `display: inline-block` so each list element can stand next to each other instead of stacking.

However, I found out that when the first image slides left it still reveals a little out of it while showing the second image, on and on and on like that, everything slides but never fully. the distance they slide is equal to the width of the image.

Also, when I get to the last image and click on next it should go back to the first image, the problem is that it displays each image along the way to the first image.

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var nextBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("nextBtn")[0],
        prevBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("prevBtn")[0];

    var i = 0;

    var imgList = document.querySelectorAll(".slide");
    var slideLength = imgList.length;
    var lastchild = imgList[slideLength - 1];
    nextBtn.addEventListener("click", Next, false);
    prevBtn.addEventListener("click", Previous, false);


    function Next() {
        console.log(slideLength)
        imgList[i].style.marginLeft = "-600px";
        if (imgList[i].classList.contains("active")) {
            imgList[i].classList.remove("active");
        }
        if (imgList[i] !== lastchild) {
            i++;
        }
        else if (imgList[i] === lastchild) {
            i = 0;
            for (var j = 0; j < slideLength; j++) {
                imgList[j].style.marginLeft = "0";
            }
        }
        imgList[i].classList.add("active");
    }

    function Previous(e) {
        console.log(i);
        if (i !== 0) {
            imgList[i - 1].style.marginLeft = "0";
            i--;
            console.log(i);
        }
        else {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
}
```

```css
ul{
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    border: solid 3px white;
    margin:100px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
li{
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(1,-0.01, 0, 1.13);
    list-style: none;

}

li img{
    width:600px;
    height:350px
}


.slide h2{
        position: absolute;
    bottom:80px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 250px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 4em;
    font-weight: 900;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <div class="container">
  <ul class="slide-wrapper">
   <li class="slide active">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
    <h2>1</h2>
   </li>
   <li class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
    <h2>2</h2>

   </li>
   <li class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
    <h2>3</h2>

   </li>
   <li class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
    <h2>4</h2>

   </li>
   <li class="slide">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" alt="">
    <h2>5</h2>

   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>


<!--<div class="test">

</div>-->
 <button class="nextBtn">Next</button>
 <button class="prevBtn">Previous</button>
```

How can I make this work well strictly with vanilla javascript? Here is the link to the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bayoamzat/a2bk4bwu/2/) . However, it doesn't seem to work at all there.

Comment: Can you create and share a JS fiddle of this? I will definitely help you.

Comment: @Abhinav I've updated the question with a link to the jsfiddle.

Comment: Fixed fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/a2bk4bwu/3/ Btw, more CSS problem than js. And also, regarding this: "Also, when I get to the last image and click on next it should go back to the first image, the problem is that it displays each image along the way to the first image." If so, you have to apply completelly different logic for slides - and change css accordingly

Comment: @sinisake what are the css issues with the code?

Comment: Inspect slide wrapper ul in your browser - and check width and position of slide it self in it...

Comment: The slide wrapper ul has a 100% width while the slide li doesn't have a width, only the image has a width. What are you trying to point out please? I tried setting the slide wrapper ul to be 600px width, but the images slide and leave a whitespace instead of revealing the next image.

Comment: @ibnhamza, set padding to 0 - remove default padding of ul element: https://jsfiddle.net/a2bk4bwu/4/ But that doesn't solve problem, either...now i see... not sure, if i find answer, will let you know...

Comment: Yep - as i assumed, inline-block elements default space causing problems - quick fix: https://jsfiddle.net/a2bk4bwu/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reference : https://jsfiddle.net/a2bk4bwu/3/

*Replace your CSS with lines with the for ul & li*

```
ul{
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    border: solid 3px white;
    margin:100px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 0;
    font-size: 0px;
}
li{
    font-size : 20px;
    display:inline-block;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 1s cubic-bezier(1,-0.01, 0, 1.13);
    list-style: none;
}
```

Things to note :

1. 'Ul' was taking extra padding by default     **{webkit-padding-start: 40px}**
2. **"display : inline-block" items are dependent on "white-space"**. So give "0px" to the parent element to remove that white space between slides.

These will fix your CSS issues.

Comment: This worked. I think I need to rewrite the whole thing, Its not smooth at all. Thanks